# Split html table values using java script

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am working in rails application and From UI I need to select around 500 parameters(comma separated) in a table for execution. I am sending those selected data in AJAX call. I am unable to post huge string values hence I am planning to get the length of selected parameters if selected parameters count exceeds length 200. I need to split two or three batches and send for execution. How to implement this?

```
if (Device1) {
  parameter_name = $('#parameters_object').val();
  var getParams=parameter_name.split(',');
  paramLen=getParams.length;
  alert(paramLen);
  if (paramLen > 200){

  }

  //m is a selected mac address length count
  for (var i = 0; i < m; i++) {

    (function () {

      var macAdd = values[i];
      $.ajax({
          method: "POST",
          url: "get_object",
          dataType: "json",
          data: {
            parameter: getParams,
            mac: macAdd,
            protocol: protocol,
            serialnumber: serialnumber,
          },

          success: function (result) {
            console.log(result);

          }
        },

        statusCode: {
        404: function () {
          console.log("Call failed");
        }
      }
    });

  })();

}
```

Comment: why this loop "for(var i = 0; i < m; i++)" ? what does 'values' contain?

Comment: m is mac address count.I can select n number of mac and execute parameters

Comment: Do you have to send a call for each values[i]? and also for each batch(200) of getParams? for example you have 4 values and 2 batches(2 * 200 = 400) of params, total 4 * 2 = 8 ajax calls will be sent

Comment: yes.My server dosen't support long url

Answer (score 1):

You can split your array into chunks of 200 items, and then loop over the chunk array and do your AJAX call.

```
const chunkSize = 200
const chunkParams = getParams.reduce((resultArray, item, index) => { 
    const chunkIndex = Math.floor(index/chunkSize)

    if(!resultArray[chunkIndex]) {
        resultArray[chunkIndex] = [] // start a new chunk
    }

    resultArray[chunkIndex].push(item)

    return resultArray
}, [])

values.forEach(macAddress => 
    chunkParams.forEach(chunkParam => 
        $.ajax({
           method: "POST",
           url: "get_object",
           dataType: "json",
           data: {
              parameter: chunkParam,
              mac: macAddress,
              ....
           },
           ...
       });
    )
)
```

You can directly do your AJAX call in the reduce loop, more performant but less readable.

Answer (score 0):

You need to split params to batches and make ajax call for each batch. Try following:

```
if (Device1) {
       parameter_name = $('#parameters_object').val();
       var getParams=parameter_name.split(',');
       paramLen=getParams.length;
        alert(paramLen)
        var paramsBatches = [];
        var batchSize = 200;
        for (i = 0, j = getParams.length; i < j; i += batchSize) {
            paramsBatches.push(getParams.slice(i, i + batchSize));
        }

        //m is a selected mac address length count
        for (var i = 0; i < m; i++) {
            paramsBatches.forEach((batch, index) => {
                var macAdd = values[i];
                $.ajax({
                    method: "POST",
                    url: "get_object",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: {
                        parameter: batch,
                        mac: macAdd,
                        protocol: protocol,
                        serialnumber: serialnumber,
                    },

                    success: function (result) {
                        console.log(result);

                        }
                    },

                    statusCode: {
                        404: function () {
                            console.log("Call failed");
                        }
                    }
                });
            }

        }

}
```

Comment: Thanks.What is array.length here

Comment: array is undefined.gerParams.length?

Comment: index do i need to set any value

Comment: what value i need to send in batch

Comment: Updated the answer. array.length(getParams.length) is the no of params. No need to set any value for index.

Comment: You no need to assign anything to batch. paramsBatches array contains getParams in batches of 200.